# subprocess error handling slipping through

Tags: python, error-handling, subprocess

I have been stuck on this a little while. Basically I have followed a number of subprocess usage examples, but I guess I must have some other issue.

I am writing a script that runs through a dir of movie files and runs `exiftool` on each of them to pull out some info about them.

I can make it work, until I strike a condition where `exiftool` errors. Such as `Error: File format error` ... so I am trying to catch that or any error that `exiftool` generates (even the error message could be handy to have as a variable), and just skip over that file.

In the below code, `myArg` is just the path to the file.

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["exiftool", "-s", "-ImageWidth", "-ImageHeight", "-VideoFrameRate", "-CompressorName", "-MediaDuration", myArg], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()
except OSError:
    print "Pass, something is borked..."
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to get the exit code from `exiftool`. It should return 0 on success, so to check for an error you can add this after your `proc.communicate()`:

```
if proc.returncode != 0:
    print "Pass, something is borked..."
```

If the error message went to stdout, you should have it in your `out` variable. If it goes to stderr, add `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to your pOpen command and then it should be in `err`.

Comment: This worked, and also helped see what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do this. You could use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) if you just want the return code:

```
import subprocess

ret = subprocess.call(['ls', 'sadknlsknfd'])
if ret:
    print('Something is borked\nreturncode:%i' % ret)

# Something is borked
# returncode:2
```

Or [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) to raise an exception:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_call(['ls', 'sadknlsknfd'])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print('Something is borked\ncommand: %s\noutput: %s\nreturncode:%i'
          % (e.cmd, e.output, e.returncode))

# Something is borked
# command: ['ls', 'sadknlsknfd']
# output: None
# returncode:2
```

Or if you want the output as well you could use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
try:
    # note that `out` will be undefined if the call fails
    out = subprocess.check_output(['ls', 'sadknlsknfd'])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print('Something is borked\ncommand: %s\noutput: %s\nreturncode:%i'
          % (e.cmd, e.output, e.returncode))

# Something is borked
# command: ['ls', 'sadknlsknfd']
# output: 
# returncode:2
```

To get the STDERR message as well, you can [redirect it to STDOUT](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

```
try:
    out = subprocess.check_output(['ls', 'sadknlsknfd'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    # `out` will be undefined if the call fails
    print('Something is borked\ncommand: %s\noutput: %s\nreturncode:%i'
          % (e.cmd, e.output, e.returncode))

# Something is borked
# command: ['ls', 'sadknlsknfd']
# output: ls: cannot access sadknlsknfd: No such file or directory

# returncode:2
```

You could also use [`subprocess.Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', 'saddsfsdf'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = p.communicate()
ret = p.returncode
if ret:
    print('Something is borked\nstdout:%s\nstderr:%s\nretcode:%i'
          % (out, err, ret))

# Something is borked
# stdout:
# stderr:ls: cannot access saddsfsdf: No such file or directory

# retcode:2
```

Comment: wow, great help, I am going to study these and play around to  see how this all works, thanks for the great examples

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to pass for any error that  can occurred while reading file,if so then generalised error handling,instead of OsError

```
except Exception as e:
   print "Error Descr"+ str(e)
   pass
```